# Change colour of text from black to white in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

Easy one, I get it but how do you change colour of text from black to white photoshop.  I've found the colour selector but I cant see white as an option(?)

Answer (score 1):

The Photoshop help files would answer this immediately for you.

[image]

or

[image]

and set the color picker to white....

[image]

Or just highlight the text, and click the white swatch in the **Swatch Panel**:

[image]

Or highlight the text and adjust the sliders in the **Color Panel**:

[image]

Comment: Scott, Why do you provide so few alternatives...? Xo)

Comment: I actually think there are at least 1 or 2 more ways I didn't mention :)

Comment: I make all of my white text by typing black text and then adding a Levels Adjustment Layer. -1 for not including Adjustment Layer solutions.

Comment: That would be one of the 2 others I thought of @Ryan ..... there's also the Color Overlay Layer Style :)